# Retrieve all rows in table B related to row in table A

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's assume I have those datasets:

Table A:

| id (int) | value (varchar) | b_ids(varchar) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a value | 1 |
| 2 | another value | 2,3 |

Table B:

| id (int) | value (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a value |
| 2 | another value |
| 3 | another another value |

The reason I have to use `b_ids` here is because the B rows have to be inserted before the A rows

I am trying to `SELECT` rows from `Table A` and the corresponding values from `Table B` in one single query, and make that query a view for filtering purposes

My attemps so far only gave me back the A rows + the first value from the related B rows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id IN (A.b_ids);
```

And I obtained something like this:

| id | value | b_ids | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a value | 1 | 1 | a value |
| 2 | another value | 2,3 | 2 | another value |

I have tried other joins (`INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`), with the same result

I obviously am still missing something in the joins department if my endeavor is even possible to do in one single SELECT

Is there a way to return the values of Table B as an array of rows in this query?

Even if the result below is the output, I can work with it:

| id | value | b_ids | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a value | 1 | 1 | a value |
| 2 | another value | 2,3 | 2 | another value |
| 2 | another value | 2,3 | 3 | another another value |

Note: I have chosen Table A as the first table here because the real case involves joins with other tables

Comment: Is `b_ids` just a `varchar` or something?  Or is there a multi-value foreign key feature in MySQL I'm just not familiar with?

Comment: I just use it as a varchar for now

Comment: I think you will have issue with this first time when you got value like `2,3,23`

Comment: @prout: If you can correct the table structure to use actual foreign keys that will make querying much easier.  (And help protect data integrity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change tables schema
if there is one to many relationship between A(1)---(n)B
tables should be like this:

Table A:

| id (int) | value (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a value |
| 2 | another value |

Table B:

| id (int) | value (varchar) | a_ids(varchar) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a value | 1 |
| 2 | another value | 2 |
| 3 | another another value | 2 |

so now you can define tables relationship or fetch data as you need in single query easily

** if tables has many to many relation you need a pivot table.

Comment: I can't insert B items after inserting A items, so I can't retrieve the ids from A in order to insert them into B

Comment: @prout: If the relationship between the records is instead meant to be many-to-many then you can introduce a linking table for that.  If you can't correct the table structure then that's going to make querying much more difficult, so that's really the recommended approach.  At the moment there doesn't appear to be anything stopping you from doing that though.

Comment: I was somehow able to insert B items after A items (one-to-many), so I guess this question is now only half relevant
I am still looking for a way to get the output of my question, but I think I will create another question with the correct formulation and structure

Comment: @prout so make 'a_ids' nullable, update table B after insert data in A, OR make a pivot table

Comment: @prout: *"I was somehow able to insert B items after A items"* - Because there's no actual foreign key constraint in your original structure.  The data in A is just a string.  It could be the string `"1,2"` or it could be the string `"t-shirt,monkey"` and it will make no difference to the data integrity.  Foreign keys exist to enforce these constraints.  (The structure in this answer uses a foreign key such that B is dependant on A, so one would *have to* insert a record into A first.)

Comment: although I'm still looking for a solution for my query, I'll mark this answer as correct for pointing me in the right approach